# How to query objects of a Parse user using his facebook ID?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

We associate every parse user to their facebook ID as in the documentation.

```
ParseFacebookUtils.link(user, this, new SaveCallback()
```

However how is it possible to query the objects of a facebook friend using his facebook ID in Parse SDK Android?

Comment: Facebook ID is the Facebook username, I reckon? If so then fetch the user name of the friend using Facebook SDK and then make a row with it (use the object).

Comment: @PsyDuck No Facebook username is not Facebook userid when using Graph API

Comment: you want to query of Facebook friends using his Facebook ID ?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you store the relationship information in Parse by associating the information with the user record. Even though Parse stores the facebook ID in the authData column, it is not queryable there.

You can get the facebook ID from the Graph API after user logs in [(link)](https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-get-the-facebook-id-of-a-user-logged-in-with-facebook) and store it as an additional column on the user record in Parse. When the user adds a friend, store this relationship in a table of your making. You can query that table to determine what the friend IDs are and access the appropriate data.

Alternately, if these queries only need to run while the user is currently logged in, you don't have to store the friend relationships. You can query the graph API (/me/friends) to get a list of friends of the user that are using your app. Facebook guarantees that they will return the same user IDs to your app each time.